# PHP : Login in to the admin page

Tags: php, html

I am trying to  login into the admin  and lecturer page in the following code.But it is not working properly.When i login  after entering loginid and password, click on submit  , no  error occured.
admin.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["userid"]))
{
    if($_SESSION["type"]=="admin")
    {
    header("Location: dashboard.php");
    }
    else
    {   
    header("Location: lectureaccount.php");
    }
}

include("header.php"); 
include("conection.php");
if(isset($_POST["uid"]) && isset($_POST["pwd"]) )
{
//  echo "sdfsd".   $_POST[uid];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM administrator WHERE adminid='$_POST[uid]'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
$pwdmd5 = $row["password"];
  }

if(md5($_POST["pwd"])=='$pwdmd5')
{
    $_SESSION["userid"] = $_POST["uid"];
    $_SESSION["type"]="admin";
    header("Location: dashboard.php");
}
else
{
$log =  "Login failed.. Please try again..";
}
}

if(isset($_POST["luid"]) && isset($_POST["lpwd"]))
{

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lectures WHERE lecid='$_POST[luid]'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
$pwdm= $row["password"];
$_SESSION["lecname"] = $row["lecname"];
$_SESSION["coid"] = $row["courseid"];
    }
//echo"pwd". md5($_POST["lpwd"]);

if(md5($_POST["lpwd"])==$pwdm)
    {
        //echo $_POST["lpwd"];
    $_SESSION["userid"] = $_POST["luid"];
    $_SESSION["type"]=="lecturer";
    header("Location: lectureaccount.php");
    }
else
    {
        $log12 =  "Login failed.. Please try again..";
    }
}
?>
<section id="page">
<header id="pageheader" class="normalheader">
<h2 class="sitedescription">
</h2>
</header>

<section id="contents">

<article class="post">
  <header class="postheader">
  <h2><u>Admin Login</u></h2>
   <?php $log = isset($_POST['log']) ?>
  <h2><?php echo $log;?></h2>
  </header>
  <section class="entry">
  <form action="admin.php" method="post" class="form">
   <p class="textfield">
      <label for="author">
             <small>Admin Login ID (required)</small>
          </label>
           <input name="uid" id="uid" value="" size="22" tabindex="1" type="text">
   </p>
   <p class="textfield">
   <label for="email">
              <small>Password (required)</small>
          </label>
       <input name="pwd" id="pwd" value="" size="22" tabindex="2" type="password">
   </p>
   <p>
     <input name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" type="image" src="images/submit.png">
     <input name="comment_post_ID" value="1" type="hidden">

   </p>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
  <form action="admin.php" method="post" class="form">
<div class="clear">
<hr />
  <header class="postheader">
    <h2><u>Lectures Login</u></h2>
   <?php $log12 = isset($_POST['log12']) ?>
   <h2><?php echo $log12;?></h2>
  </header>
  <section class="entry">

      <p class="textfield">
        <label for="author2"> <small><br />
          Lecture Login ID (required)</small> </label>
        <input name="luid" id="luid" value="" size="22" tabindex="3" type="text" />
      </p>
      <p class="textfield">
        <label for="email2"> <small>Password (required)</small> </label>
        <input name="lpwd" id="lpwd" size="22" tabindex="4" type="password" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input name="submit2" id="submit2" tabindex="5" type="image" src="images/submit.png" />
        <input name="comment_post_ID2" value="1" type="hidden" />
      </p>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </section>
</div>
</section>
</article>
</section>

<?php 
include("adminmenu.php");
include("footer.php"); ?>
```

Database:
table fields in administrator are:   adminid,password,adminname,address,contactno
table fields in lectures are:
lecid,password,courseid,lecname,gender,address,contactno.

Please provide solution for this issue.

Comment: Can you change the code `if(md5($_POST["pwd"])=='$pwdmd5')` to `if(md5($_POST["pwd"])==$pwdmd5)` ?

Comment: Look into prepared statements; currently you are open to SQL injections. Send the password with the query, no need to check later. MD5 isn't the best hashing mechanism anymore (better than plain text though).

Comment: As chris85 said, you should seriously move away from plain MySQL and MD5. Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Answer (score 0):

instead of using this code

```
if(md5($_POST["pwd"])=='$pwdmd5')
```

use this

```
if(md5($_POST["pwd"])==$pwdmd5)
```

In the first case, the hashed pasword is compared to the string `$pwdmd5`, in the second to the content of $pwdmd5